# How to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\sinh^a x\cdot \cosh^b x \cdot e^{cx}$ at $x=0$

Tags: taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

As the title shows, I'm looking to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in  $$\sinh^a x\cdot \cosh^b x \cdot e^{cx}$$ at $x=0$, as a follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316649/number-of-ways-of-dividing-objects/2317286#2317286) question. Expressing the hyperbolic functions in terms of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ doesn't do much to simplify the question.

Maybe I'm missing something, but perhaps this closed form is too complicated to be found?

Comment: [Cauchy products?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)

Comment: $a,b\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Sorry, the notification wasn't updated properly. Yes, $a, b$ are natural numbers, starting from $0$.